# In Singaporean English, what does the phrase 'Ok, Ken' mean?

Tags: singapore-english

I was in a training session today with a Singaporean trainer (lah!) and he kept using the phrase:

> "Ok, Ken"

I checked the meeting attendees for a 'Ken' - but there was definitely no 'Ken' in the room.

He kept repeating it, also using the phrase:

> "Alright, Ken".

Eventually I inferred that he must be using a contracted version of:

> "**Ok**, I am confident that you **can** do this."

But I wasn't sure.

I didn't know whether this was a Singaporean English expression (lah!) or if he was just taking a Mandarin phrase in his head, and translating it directly into English.

My question is: **In Singaporean English, what does the phrase 'Ok, Ken' mean?**

---

The context was an IT Training course. For example:

> Trainer: Here is how to install Azure Migration assistant and perform a Cloud Migration.
>
> [Performs 25 steps]
>
> Trainer: So that is how you use Azure Migration assistant. Ok can.

Or another example

> Attendee: [Complicated question]
>
> Trainer: It's easy!
>
> [Talks through 15 steps]
>
> Trainer: So that is how you do it. Alright can.

Comment: I think you may be hearing the Singlish (Singapore English-based creole language) "OK kena" (“kena” is a Malay term which denotes that something has happened to someone or something.) Possibly "OK kena" means that a topic or matter is complete.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Harvey. Can you expand that into an answer?

Comment: It's just a guess. An answer needs to be based on knowledge, with references.

Comment: Great question. Could you give a little bit more context, like what the sentence by the other speaker was that elicited 'OK ken.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Miel's [An Essential Guide to Singaporean English](https://www.amazon.com.au/An-Essential-Guide-to-Singlish/dp/9810861095) - there are many phrases that use ***can*** as a verb in a distinctly Singaporean phrasing.

In this context - "ok Ken" is actually "Ok can" ie "ok can do".

And "also Ken" is "Yes I can too".

[image]

[image]

Comment: All those examples have 'can' at the beginning, but the OP  is asking about it at the end. Do you have any Singlish teaching examples which use it as a particle at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 4):

My Singaporean colleague told me that **"Ok ken"** or **"Ok can"** is the way to confirm or acknowledge that somebody will do something.

According to her, this phrase originates from Chinese Mandarin **"好的，行" (hao3 de1, xing2)**. The word **"行" (xing2)** in Chinese means something is good, ok, can be performed, and ok can do. So Singaporean Chinese people simply converted to English with the word "Can" to represent the Chinese word **行** so whenever they confirm they'll do something, it's **"ok can / ok ken"**.